# SSL certificate validation for a proxy connection using python requests

Tags: ssl, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to a site, e.g www.yahoo.com via proxy using python requests library. So, I define proxy settings as:

```
HOST = 'host'
PORT = 1234 # random port I have used here
USER = 'user'
PASS = 'password'
PROXY = "%s:%s@%s:%d" % (USER, PASS, HOST, PORT)
PROXY_DICT = {
    "http"  : 'http://' + PROXY, 
    "https" : 'https://' + PROXY, 
    }
```

I use the following line of code:

```
requests.get('http://www.yahoo.com', proxies=proxy_dict)
```

This doesn't raise an exception but the response text is an error page from the proxy saying **"Ensure you have installed the certificate"**. I have a certificate **"certificate.crt"**, which runs fine when used with chrome browser. And the certificate is self-signed. I have tried a couple of things which raise errors.

When used the crt file as a verify param, following error:

```
SSLError: [Errno bad ca_certs: 'certificate.crt'] []
```

When used the crt file as a cert param, following error:

```
Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file', 'PEM lib')]
```

I managed to get a **.pem file**(I'm not sure but, it **might have been generated using a key and a crt file**) as well. When using it with cert param, it doesn't throw error, but the response text is again having the text "...**Ensure that the certificate is installed**..."

When used **.pem file** with verify param, following error:

```
SSLError: [Errno bad handshake] [('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')]
```

Now when I refer to requests docs, I see I can use two parameters verify and cert. What shall I use here? And how?

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue ?